# Finding MAX column BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, normalization

I am attempting to 'normalize' the data in a column so it ranges between 0 and 1. My initial plan was to find the MAX value of the column and perform the following calculation:
column/MAX(column). The problem I am having is that the output looks like this

[image]

It goes on like that...

Obviously it seems that my query is pulling the max of that particular row, which as it only has one value, matches said value and the normalized data is always one.

Here is the query I used to find the pageviews (the data is from GA and the schema is unchanged from the default):

```
SELECT
  pageTitle, 
  COUNT(*) AS pageviews

FROM (
  SELECT
     hits.page.pageTitle,
     hits.type,

    FROM
    `medicine-matter.131114627.ga_sessions_*` AS GA,
    UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits

    WHERE
    type = 'PAGE'

     )
    GROUP BY
    pageTitle

    ORDER BY
    pageviewDESC
```

I am then calling the pageviews in another table like so:

```
SELECT
pageviews,
MAX(pageviews) as MAX,
pageviews/ MAX(pageviews) as normal_pageview


FROM
`table`
WHERE
pageviews > 1

group by 
pageTitle,
pageviews

ORDER BY
normal_pageview DESC
```

I am very new to SQL so i can only apologies if i am doing something absolutely moronic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT pageviews, 
  MAX(pageviews) OVER() max_pageviews,
  ROUND(pageviews / MAX(pageviews) OVER(), 2) normal_pageviews
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 22 pageviews UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 24 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 
)
SELECT pageviews, 
  MAX(pageviews) OVER() max_pageviews,
  ROUND(pageviews / MAX(pageviews) OVER(), 2) normal_pageviews
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row pageviews   max_pageviews   normal_pageviews     
1   22          99              0.22     
2   4           99              0.04     
3   14          99              0.14     
4   99          99              1.0  
5   24          99              0.24     
6   4           99              0.04     
7   8           99              0.08
```

Hope you can easily adjust above to your real case

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly. So OVER() is just telling to to max over all the results not just the row?

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting solution for BigQuery Standard SQL with the help of BigQuery ML Preprocessing function - [ML.MIN_MAX_SCALER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-preprocessing-functions#mlmin_max_scaler)

> Scales the numerical_expression to [0, 1] capped with MIN and MAX across all rows

```
#standardSQL
SELECT pageviews, 
  ROUND(ML.MIN_MAX_SCALER(pageviews) OVER(), 2) normal_pageviews
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```